Why doesn't the user card have a blue background when a question asker edits another user's answer to their question?
Since question askers have a blue background in their user card for answers and comments they author on their own questions, as a matter of consistency I assume they should also have it on the user card displayed when they edited another user's answer to their question.
For example, it's the case with this answer.
Is this a bug or are there reasons behind that inconsistency?

I had thought it was associated with the role (asking the question), not the user.  But when you actually write an answer to your own question, you do get a blue background. Curious.

I don't know if it's intentional but, IMO, makes sense. The display gets more busy when adding the highlight but I don't think it's meaningful information whether the editor was the question asker or not. It's more meaningful to know whether the question asker commented or answered.

AFAIK, it's not a bug, in a sense that it has been like that since long time ago. OTOH, I wonder if adding background color might make the UX worse, since users already mistook an editor as the answerer.

It's not an inconsistency. The 'blue background' on the user card denotes original authorship of that content within the context of that Q&A thread for reference purposes in scenarios where there can be many different user cards appearing.
An edit to a post does not make you the original author of the post, and there can only be one most recent editor, unlike with comments or answers, of which there can be many; it is useful to tell at a glance whether the question asker authored an answer or responded via a comment somewhere. It is not useful to tell whether the question asker was the one to edit a post (not least of which because, for answers at least, there's very little cause for askers to edit other peoples' answers to their questions ).

This principle doesn't make sense, according to that, you should have the blue (or grey here on meta) background on this answer and if you reply to this comment you should also have it (spoiler: you won't). Also I have it on this comment while not being the original author of your answer. Add to that, on the linked answer, the answerer doesn't have the blue background

Maybe you're mistakenly thinking I'm talking about the edit history? (.../revisions)

No, I understood you correctly; you're talking about the usercard that shows in the middle of the bottom of a post when it's been edited by someone other than the answer author. It isn't blue/grey for me here because I'm not the original author of this thread, you are. You are showing as blue/grey because you are the original author of the thread, and the original author of the post.

I added more detail to my answer to make it more clear why this isn't inconsistent.

So you're saying (like most comments on my question) that having it would be pointless, if not bad. But that doesn't make it less inconsistent IMO. Anyways, I still find the first paragraph wrong

No, I'm saying you just don't understand what the use is for, so you are thinking its application is inconsistent. My argument is that, once you understand the use case for the feature, you'll see that it is in fact consistent.
